# CatBoost border

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, catboost

I can't start catboost learning with catboost because of a small border.

```
X = pandas.read_csv("../input/x_y_test/X.csv")
X_test = pandas.read_csv("../input/x_y_test/X_test.csv")
y = pandas.read_csv("../input/y-data/y.csv")

X = X.reset_index(drop = True)
X_test = X_test.reset_index(drop = True)
y = y.reset_index(drop = True)

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = .3, random_state = 1337)

X_train = X_train.reset_index(drop = True) 
X_val = X_val.reset_index(drop = True)
y_train = y_train.reset_index(drop = True)
y_val = y_val.reset_index(drop = True)

model_cb = CatBoostClassifier(eval_metric = "Accuracy", n_estimators = 1200, random_seed = 70)
model_cb.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set = (X_val, y_val), use_best_model = True)
```

so I got

```
CatboostError: catboost/libs/metrics/metric.cpp:3929: All train targets are greater than border 0.5
```

data

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1m7bNIs0mZQQkAsvkETB3n6j62p9QJX39?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main error is that you're feeding `y_train` to your algo as:

```
    id  skilled
0   138177  0
1   36214   0
2   103206  1
3   22699   1
4   96145   1
```

I believe what you really intended was just `y_train.skilled`

Run reassignment like below before your fitting and you're fine to go:

```
y_train = y_train.skilled # just skill is enough 
y_val = y_val.skilled # just skill is enough

model_cb = CatBoostClassifier(eval_metric = "Accuracy", n_estimators = 1200, random_seed = 70)
model_cb.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set = (X_val, y_val), use_best_model = True)
```

On a side note, do you really believe `id` in `X_train` possesses any predictive ability. Why not drop it from features as well?

Comment: Note: for people using `MultiLogloss` or `MultiCrossEntropy`, this issue might occur when some categories in the training set has only zeroes.